# .NET/html, element does not exist error when selecting dropdown.ClientID

Tags: asp.net, html

On button click I want to get the value of a dropdown but for somereason when I go into the code it fails with error 'Exdd' does not exist in the current context. The ExTypeDD is in my listview as a dropdown and I'm just trying to get the value from it. The server side is generating this code and not my browser.

```
$('.Updt')
 .click(function() {

            var parent = $(this).parent().prev();

            var TypeNode = parent.children("#<%=Exdd.ClientID %>").first();


 <asp:ListView runat="server" id="ListView1" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="tablesorter" style="border:solid 1px black;width:55%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Address</a>
                         </th>                                                                                                            
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="Exdd"
                             class="Nbr1" style="width: 90px" >
                            <option value=""><%# Eval("Type")%></option>
                            <option value="0">Home</option></select>
                </td>
    <td>
              <input type="button" id="btn_update" class="Updt" value="Update" />
    </td>
             </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What is generating the error - your server-side code, or the browser?

Comment: server side. as its stepping through program

Comment: Ok. I am re-tagging your question. This has nothing to do with the client-side code.

Comment: Server-side, how are you trying to access the control?

Comment: I'm accessing it on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a ListView. You have as `ExTypeDD` as you have rows.
So you can not reference `ExTypeDD` successfully outside of the item template (there are more than one)

You may try ( after wrapping that up in a `$(document).ready` )

```
$('.Updt')
 .click(function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var TypeNode = tr.find("select.Nbr1").first();
         //...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to access an HTML element on the server side as a server side control. You could make your `select` element into a server side control by simply adding `runat="server"` to it like such:

```
<select id="ExTypeDD" runat="server" class="Nbr1" style="width:90px">
```

But after that you would still have the issue that this control, although accessible on the server side now, it does not have the id of ExTypeDD because it is dynamically created in the ItemTemplate of your ListView which generates a unique ID value for each newly created control . You can verify this by viewing source on the page rendered in the browser and checking the ID value on the select element.

To do what you're trying to do on the server side you would need to do something along the lines of this:

Add an onItemCreated event handler to your ListView:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" id="ListView1" onItemCreated="ListView1ItemCreated">
```

Replace this:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_update" class="Updt" value="Update" />
```

With this:

```
<asp:button id="btn_update" text="Update" runat="server" />
```

Add the event handler to the code behind:

```
protected void ListView1ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e){
   var myselect = (HtmlSelect)e.Item.FindControl("ExTypeDD");
   var mybutton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_update");
   mybutton.OnSubmit += (o,e) => {  
      // do something with myselect selected value
      var selectedvalue = myselect.Value;
   };
}
```

**NOTE: the above code is not tested and probably won't compile, you will need to make necessary corrections, but it should give you the idea for a way to solve your problem. Hope it helps.**

Comment: I unfortunately must use HTML type buttons and not asp buttons as they are more manangeable for end users.

Comment: In that case you can not access the button or the select element on the server side directly as you would do with a server sie control, so you should use a client side solution along the lines of @jbl's answer